# Is it possible to send a tweet including hyperlink using TweetSharp?

Tags: twitter, tweetsharp

I am using TweetSharp in my current project and am trying to send tweets that contain URLs.

When I look at the tweets once they are posted, the Urls are not displayed as hyperlinks just plain text.

I read that Tweetsharp supports entities, but from what i can see thats only once a tweet has been retrieved from Twitter.

I have tried including the link as HTML when sending the tweet, but that just results in the tweet not sending at all.

This is the code I am using:

```
 var service = new TwitterService(twitterApiKey, twitterApiSecret);
        service.AuthenticateWith(unencryptedToken, unencryptedSecret);

        model.Message = string.Concat(model.Message, " ", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ShortenedUrl) ? model.ShortenedUrl : model.CurrentUrl);

        if (model.Image == null)
        {
            var tweet = service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions {Status = model.Message});

            if (tweet == null)
                return false;

        }
        else
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(model.Image.FileLocation, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var images = new Dictionary<string, Stream> {{"image", stream}};
                var tweetwithMedia = service.SendTweetWithMedia(new SendTweetWithMediaOptions
                    {
                        Status = model.Message,
                        Images = images
                    });

                if (tweetwithMedia == null)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
```

The model.Message is just a string.

Does anyone know how to display the links correctly.

Cheers

Comment: "the Urls are not displayed as hyperlinks just plain text" - can you include an example?

Comment: @Fresh Basically if i tweet anything with say http://www.google.com in it. It would not be clickable on twitter when people view it. It would just appear as plain text.